# twitter bootstrap - getting a badge beside a list item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am needing help using twitters bootstrap. (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html)

I am using a list

```
<li>
```

With a badge I want displayed beside the list items text, problem is it keeps going below the text as if it's not in the list item?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="/admin.php">Admin CP</a> <span class="badge badge-important">1</span></li>
```

Here's an image that shows the admin cp link with a badge below it: http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3645/screenshotfrom201305201.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Include the `span` inside the anchor tag like this:

```
<li><a href="/admin.php">Admin CP <span class="badge badge-important">1</span> </a></li>
```

And double check that the `span` tag doesn't have declared `display:block` nor `display:block-inline` somewhere. That might be the reason.

**UPDATE**

Also it might help forcing the badge to float intentionally like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-important pull-right">1</span>
```

Hope this helps!